# Meteor.call checking array parameter

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am doing a `Meteor.call('searchDatabase', keys...)` that is executed whenever a user submits a search. I am currently passing an array of the words submitted called `keys`. However, I do not know how to do the necessary `check(keys, ?)` on the server side. I originally thought that I could do `keys.forEach(function(element) { check(element, String)}`, but i still get a `Did not check() all arguments` error. Should i just pass the submitted search as its original string in the Meteor method call and then break it up on the server? or is there a way to check that keys is an array?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `keys` is an array of strings, you can just do:

```
check(keys, [String]);
```

Your method would look something like:

```
Meteor.methods({
  searchDatabase: function(keys) {
    check(keys, [String]);
    // add other method code here
  }
})
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anybody else, I recast the answer from the [Meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/check-object-in-an-array/3355/4) to use arrow functions and avoid underscore and duplicate declarations:

```
check(subscriptions, Match.Where((myArray) => {
    myArray.forEach((myObject) => {
        /* do your checks and return false if there is a problem */
    });
    // return true if there is no problem
    return true;
}));
```

This checks an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

As shown here: https://forums.meteor.com/t/check-object-in-an-array/3355

```
var subscriptions = [
  {/* ... */},
  {/* ... */},
  {/* ... */}
];

check(subscriptions, Match.Where(function(subscriptions){
  _.each(subscriptions, function (doc) {
    /* do your checks and return false if there is a problem */
  });
  // return true if there is no problem
  return true;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema), you should try this way:

```
check( keys, [ mySchema ] );
```

You can learn more about check patterns in this link
[using-the-check-package](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-check-package/)